# Is Ajax call the best way to update a field every 5 seconds (Live) in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I need to check the database if a new row is created for the user and show him a popup message. I should do it for every user, and it should happen without refreshing the page (Live). Shall I try pusher/socket or make Ajax call every 5 seconds? I really want to use Ajax because it's easier and straightforward.
The related table has nearly 50,000 rows, and I'll need to check if a new row with the particular user_id is added through a postback.

Answer (score 3):

Since the information needs to be transmitted from the server (at some unknown time) to the client, it would be far more elegant to use a [WebSocket](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#introduction) ([JS docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)). This way, instead of the client having to repeatedly ping the server, the client just has to establish a socket connection *once*, and the server can send the data whenever it's ready.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `setInterval` function in JS for call Ajax function.

```
function checkAjaxFunc() { ... }
setInterval(function() {checkAjaxFunc()},5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not a scheduled task?
See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling)

You could set a cache value every five second and in ajax call read only this value. in this way you will not read DB and only a cache value every 5 seconds instead of once every 5 seconds for each user logged in